Do both of the Weapons need the Nick Weapon Mastery for it to work, a specific one of the two or any?
Reading the Nick Weapon Mastery, I am left wondering how exactly it works. Of course both weapons need to be light to be able to make that Extra Attack with light weapons, but which of the weapons needs to have the Nick Weapon Mastery? Is it both or only one? If it's only one does it have to be a specific one, i.e. the one you make the original attack with or the one you make the Extra attack with or does it not matter?
Having now read through the rules of the Light weapon property and Nick several times, I personally don't see any clear indication one way or the other, which is why I am asking if someone here might be able to decipher those rules for me. Nick states that it applies "when you make the extra Attack of the light property", this to me could mean it might be the weapon that does the Extra Attack that needs to have Nick, but I am really not sure if I am intrepreting that correctly, I mean it could also be that, when the Nick Weapon makes the first attack, that that enables the other light weapon (Nick or not) to make its attack as part of the action.
As an example imagine a character is attacking with a Dagger (which has Nick) in one-hand and a Shortsword (which has Vex) in the other hand. Can they make use of Nick? Do they have to attack with a specific weapon first or last for that to work? The rogue in my group, which I DM, has daggers and has recently purchased a shortsword, and we will be changing to the 2024 version in the next couple of months, meaning that this might be something that will come at my table not that for into the future.
Interestingly the Rogue's new starting Equipment (A) now gives them 2 daggers and 1 shortsword and the Ranger's starting equipment (A), as well as the Fighter's starting equipment (B) give them a Scimitar (which also have Nick) instead of the daggers. These setups seem to me to heavily imply, that Nick works with only one weapon having it, though that by itself is not yet a proof.

The weapon used for the extra attack must have the Nick property
The wording of Nick is indeed confusing, and comparing the description of Nick to all the other mastery properties reveals why: Nick is the only mastery property that doesn't include the phrase "this weapon". Despite this, the description of mastery properties can help us here (emphasis added):

Each weapon has a mastery property, which is usable only by a character who has a feature, such as Weapon Mastery, that unlocks the property for the character.

A mastery property is a property of the weapon, and every mastery property's effect involves an attack in some way. This means that for each attack, there can only be one mastery property involved: the mastery property of the weapon used in that specific attack. Specifically, Nick applies only to attacks made with a weapon that has the Nick property, just like every other mastery property. Unlike the other properties, though, Nick further limits its use to "when you make the extra attack of the Light property". Putting these together, Nick applies specifically when you make the extra attack of the Light property using a weapon with the Nick property. Notably, there are no additional conditions placed on how you must trigger this extra attack. In particular, there is no requirement to attack with a Nick weapon first as part of your action in order to "activate" the Nick property. Any extra attack of the Light property is eligible for Nick regardless of how it was triggered.
In other words, the ambiguously worded description of the Nick property in the PHB is equivalent to the following more explicit one (change highlighted in bold):

Nick
When you make the extra attack of the Light property using this weapon, you can make it as part of the Attack action instead of as a Bonus Action. You can make this extra attack only once per turn.

I'm not sure why Nick deviates from all the other mastery properties by omitting the phrase "this weapon," and I wouldn't be surprised if this was changed in a future erratum. But I still think the above is the only reasonable way to interpret the property as it is currently written.

I thought so too first, and also read the intro paragraph, unfortunately the paragraph does not actually say that the weapon's mastery property must use the weapon. It says mastery "unlocks the property for the character", not "for the weapon". If you look at the Light property, it says the Extra Attack "must me made with a different Light weapon". I think your take is a sane interpretation of how it should work (i.e. you can only use nick on Light extra attack replacement, not on the triggering original attack with a Light weapon), but this surely would benefit from clarifying language.

@NobodytheHobgoblin But the description also explains what "unlocks the property for the character" means: it means that weapon's mastery property is usable by the character. It's still a property of the weapon, so I don't think it makes any sense to apply it to attacks made with other weapons unless it specifically says so (which no mastery property does). That said, I agree the wording could be a lot clearer. Literally every other weapon property (mastery or otherwise) specifies that it only applies to weapons with that property.

@NobodytheHobgoblin More specifically, I think this is not just a sane interpretation, but the only sane interpretation. The only other possible interpretation would be that Nick mastery always applies to every Light extra attack, as long as the character has mastery of any one weapon with the Nick property. And I wouldn't call that a sane interpretation. Any other interpretation would be imputing arbitrary additional requirements, such as possessing/equipping a Nick weapon. "Using this weapon" is the only additional requirement we can infer, based on Nick being a property of the weapon.

The other interpretation I could see is that if you attack first with a Light weapon that has Nick, then whatever other Light weapon you hold in the other hand can be used for an extra attack without needing a Bonus Action, because you attacked with a weapon that has Nick with mastery and that allows you to now "make the extra attack of the Light property, (...) as part of the Attack action instead of as a Bonus Action." - maybe because the first attack marked or distracted your target so it now is easier to stab with the other hand or such. I don't think this reading is 100% excluded.

@NobodytheHobgoblin I don't think that reading is consistent the wording they use, because the Nick property only applies "when you make the extra attack of the Light property". This means that Nick doesn't do anything until after you've already met the conditions for making this type of extra attack. If an attack was already part of your Attack action, that attack does not meet the conditions for using the Nick property.

@NobodytheHobgoblin You guys should probably move this discussion to chat.

@TreeSpawned You only get the chat-moving option after a certain number of backs-and-forths, and I didn't see it yet. I think also I've exahausted the comments I had, with nothing more to add - I think RCT's view is the most reasonable one, but really would like to see an official clarification on this - dual wielders are a common enough trope you shouldn't have to piece together how they work with this level of forensics on rules wording. And they have been sloppy before, where the answer turned out to be not in the rules as written.

@NobodytheHobgoblin Yeah the wording is really unclear. I would also love to seen errata of this.

I think you should emphasize that it's only the extra attack weapon that needs to be Nick, not both. E.g. mainhanding a shortsword offhanding a scimitar gets you vex on the normal attacks (if you have two masteries)

The weapon used for the first attack must have the Nick property
Ryan C. Thompson's answer makes sense, and is a perfectly fine ruling. But I read the Nick property a bit differently. All weapons with nick also have the Light property. So what the Nick property does, in my eyes, is augment the Light property. The relevant part of the light property says:

Light: When you take the Attack action on your turn and attack with a Light weapon, you can make one extra attack as a Bonus Action later on the same turn.

And the relevant part of Nick says:

Nick: When you make the extra attack of the Light property, you can make it as part of the Attack action instead of as a Bonus Action.

So in normal circumstances, without Weapon Mastery, when you attack with a Light weapon you can make an extra attack with a bonus action. When you attack with a Light weapon that has the Nick property, you get the opportunity to make an attack as a bonus action as normal, or you can make that attack as part of the Attack action.
The Nick property still only applies to attacks made with the Nick weapon, but instead of affecting the attack itself, it affects what options you get access to after making the attack.

This article helped me to understand how Nick works: https://www.dndbeyond.com/posts/1742-your-guide-to-weapon-mastery-in-the-2024-players

@Tarod I don't really see how that clears up anything. There is no mention of whether the Nick weapon is the weapon that can be used to make the extra attack in the same action or if it's the weapon that enables you to make an extra attack in the same action.

This sentence. "How to Use Weapon Mastery Properties: If you’re wielding a weapon and have learned its mastery property, you’ll be able to use that mastery property every turn when you make an attack with the weapon."

Yes, so every turn with a Nick weapon you can give yourself an additional attack through the Light property that you can take as a part of the same Attack action.

But you must attack with the weapon that has the Nick property for that extra attack. Anyway, your answer is how other people are understanding the rules, so it's also a valid interpretation, IMO.

Must you? That's what this question is about, and I don't think the rules are clear.

Well, you know... it's how I see it, but as I said, I can also understand there are others POV on this topic.
